# Build dependencies error while ultralytics installing [errno 111]

Tags: ubuntu, pip

I try to install ultralytics on Ubuntu 20.04 vm under the corporate network.
Unfortunatelly I've stucked with build dependencies error.

Issue occurs only with ultralytics. Other libraries installs fine.
pip 23.2.1
python 3.8.10
setuptools 68.2.2

I use tmp folder on home disc because ultralytics demands a lot if space. Also I use corporate proxy to get acces to lybraries.
Initial request: **TMPDIR=/home/usr/tmp/ pip install --cache-dir=/home/usr/tmp/ --proxy http://*user:password@proxy:port*-U ultralytics**

Here are details about the error.
Could you help me with the direction to dig further?)

```
Collecting ultralytics
  Obtaining dependency information for ultralytics from *url deleted to pass spam check* ultralytics-8.0.184-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached ultralytics-8.0.184-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (28 kB)
Collecting matplotlib>=3.3.0 (from ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for matplotlib>=3.3.0 from files.pythonhosted on org/packages/08/73/a4af3493a81d6e5e1fdb4c72f4d3573a7e94b60f7c2c69ab0275fdc7cd8e/matplotlib-3.7.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Using cached matplotlib-3.7.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl.metadata (5.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.22.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ultralytics) (1.24.4)
Collecting opencv-python>=4.6.0 (from ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for opencv-python>=4.6.0 from *url deleted to pass spam check* opencv_python-4.8.0.76-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Using cached opencv_python-4.8.0.76-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (19 kB)
Collecting pillow>=7.1.2 (from ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for pillow>=7.1.2 from *url deleted to pass spam check*Pillow-10.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Using cached Pillow-10.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata (9.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.3.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ultralytics) (6.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.23.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ultralytics) (2.31.0)
Collecting scipy>=1.4.1 (from ultralytics)
  Using cached scipy-1.10.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (34.5 MB)
Collecting torch>=1.8.0 (from ultralytics)
  Using cached torch-2.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (619.9 MB)
Collecting torchvision>=0.9.0 (from ultralytics)
  Using cached torchvision-0.15.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (33.8 MB)
Collecting tqdm>=4.64.0 (from ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for tqdm>=4.64.0 from *url deleted to pass spam check*tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (57 kB)
Collecting pandas>=1.1.4 (from ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for pandas>=1.1.4 from *url deleted to pass spam check*pandas-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Using cached pandas-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting seaborn>=0.11.0 (from ultralytics)
  Using cached seaborn-0.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (293 kB)
Collecting psutil (from ultralytics)
  Using cached psutil-5.9.5-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (282 kB)
Collecting py-cpuinfo (from ultralytics)
  Using cached py_cpuinfo-9.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for contourpy>=1.0.1 from *url deleted to pass spam check*contourpy-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Using cached contourpy-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (5.9 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0 (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for fonttools>=4.22.0 from *url deleted to pass spam check*fonttools-4.42.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Using cached fonttools-4.42.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (150 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for kiwisolver>=1.0.1 from *url deleted to pass spam check*kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
Collecting packaging>=20.0 (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached packaging-23.1-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.3.1 (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for pyparsing>=2.3.1 from *url deleted to pass spam check*pyparsing-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached pyparsing-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics) (2.8.2)
Collecting importlib-resources>=3.2.0 (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for importlib-resources>=3.2.0 from *url deleted to pass spam check*importlib_resources-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached importlib_resources-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
Collecting pytz>=2020.1 (from pandas>=1.1.4->ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for pytz>=2020.1 from *url deleted to pass spam check*pytz-2023.3.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached pytz-2023.3.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (22 kB)
Collecting tzdata>=2022.1 (from pandas>=1.1.4->ultralytics)
  Using cached tzdata-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (341 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->ultralytics) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->ultralytics) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->ultralytics) (1.26.16)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->ultralytics) (2023.7.22)
Collecting filelock (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for filelock from *url deleted to pass spam check*filelock-3.12.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached filelock-3.12.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for typing-extensions from *url deleted to pass spam check*typing_extensions-4.8.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.8.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting sympy (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached sympy-1.12-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 MB)
Collecting networkx (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached networkx-3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics) (3.1.2)
Collecting nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.7.99 (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached nvidia_cuda_nvrtc_cu11-11.7.99-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (21.0 MB)
Collecting nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.7.99 (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached nvidia_cuda_runtime_cu11-11.7.99-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (849 kB)
Collecting nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11==11.7.101 (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached nvidia_cuda_cupti_cu11-11.7.101-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.8 MB)
Collecting nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96 (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached nvidia_cudnn_cu11-8.5.0.96-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (557.1 MB)
Collecting nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66 (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached nvidia_cublas_cu11-11.10.3.66-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (317.1 MB)
Collecting nvidia-cufft-cu11==10.9.0.58 (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached nvidia_cufft_cu11-10.9.0.58-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (168.4 MB)
Collecting nvidia-curand-cu11==10.2.10.91 (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached nvidia_curand_cu11-10.2.10.91-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (54.6 MB)
Collecting nvidia-cusolver-cu11==11.4.0.1 (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached nvidia_cusolver_cu11-11.4.0.1-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (102.6 MB)
Collecting nvidia-cusparse-cu11==11.7.4.91 (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached nvidia_cusparse_cu11-11.7.4.91-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (173.2 MB)
Collecting nvidia-nccl-cu11==2.14.3 (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached nvidia_nccl_cu11-2.14.3-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (177.1 MB)
Collecting nvidia-nvtx-cu11==11.7.91 (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached nvidia_nvtx_cu11-11.7.91-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (98 kB)
Collecting triton==2.0.0 (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached triton-2.0.0-1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.whl (63.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66->torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics) (68.2.2)
Collecting wheel (from nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66->torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for wheel from *url deleted to pass spam check*wheel-0.41.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached wheel-0.41.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting cmake (from triton==2.0.0->torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Obtaining dependency information for cmake from *url deleted to pass spam check*cmake-3.27.5-py2.py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Using cached cmake-3.27.5-py2.py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.whl.metadata (6.7 kB)
Collecting lit (from triton==2.0.0->torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics)
  Using cached lit-16.0.6.tar.gz (153 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f07b85d9430>: Failed to establish a new connection: **[Errno 111] Connection refused**')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f07b85d97c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f07b85d9ac0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f07b85d9c70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f07b85d9e20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /simple/setuptools/
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I've updated pip and setuptools to the last version.
Tried setuptools==57.5.0
Tried it both in venv and on a main machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution.
To solve this problem I've added proxy in pip config.
Here are instuction:

1. python3 -m pip config debug
2. Find whether it's an existing pip.conf. If so ego to next step. In my case there was no config, so I created a directory **sudo mkdir /etc/xdg/pip/**
3. Open config: **sudo vim /etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf**
4. Add proxy to pip.conf

[global]

proxy = http://user:password@proxy_name:port